# How to ajax(jquery) to php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having problems with my Post to the php file.

I already test this(below) and its working fine

```
<?php

$fto = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$fsubject = 'Test';
$fmessage = 'Message';
$fheaders = 'From: test@test.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($fto, $fsubject, $fmessage, $fheaders);

?>
```

But i'm trying to use an ajax to send it for me but for some reason it's not working :c

I tried this :

(PHP)

```
<?php

$fto = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$fsubject = $_POST['subj'];
$fmessage = $_POST['all'];
$fheaders = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($fto, $fsubject, $fmessage, $fheaders);

?>
```

(Jquery)

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var text = $("#message").val();

  var subj = "Novo Parceiro - " + name;

  var all = "Nome : " + name + "\nE-mail : " + email + "\nMensagem : " + text;

  var dataString = name + email + text + all + subj;

  if (name.length > 3){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/scripts/mailform.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
       $('#form').trigger("reset");
    }
    });
  } else{
       $('#errorform').slideDown(200);
  }

  return false;
});
```

Comment: is the data getting passed to your PHP code correctly ?

Comment: You have to format that data! You can't just combine variables like that and try to pull them out!

Comment: instead of sending data as string, it would be better to have a json object as it makes things more clear: `var dataJSON = {name: name, email: email, text:text, all: all, subj:subj};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not constructing the string properly:

```
var dataString = "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&text="+text+"&all="+all+"&subj="+subj;
```

The post variables you are receiving will now work.

On a side note, please do some type of validation on that `$_POST[]` input, otherwise it can be injected and taken over to inject server-side code which would have some negative consequences.

Comment: Thanks !
About the validation, what do you mean ?

Comment: @user2136984 Because of the way your code is written, I could inject an `;` to stop interpretation of the string, and then I could execute code on the server afterwards, such as detailed file path information, or, just delete all your files instead.

Comment: oh... Do you have any tutorial or something ? I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery ajax call change the data parameter to:

```
if (name.length > 3){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/scripts/mailform.php",
    data: {name:name, email:email,text:text,all:all,subj:subj};
    success: function(){
       $('#form').trigger("reset");
    }
});
```

jquery will take care of encoding the supplied object into `application/www-form-urlencoded` format

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return false if you're already preventing the default action... Also, you can simplify this function with the serialize method, and move the message formatting (i.e. `"Nome : " + name + etc.`) to the server:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var $dataString = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/scripts/mailform.php",
            data: $dataString,
            success: function(data) {
               $(this).trigger("reset");
            }
        });

});
```